# Makefile:619: recipe for target '.build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin' failed error at caffe installation on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, caffe

I'm trying install BVLC Caffe framework on ubuntu 16.04. I go through all installation steps at their own github [site](https://github.com/BVLC/caffe). When I type "make all" I get this errors :

> CXX/LD -o .build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin /usr/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lLIBRARIES /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -l+= /usr/bin/ld:
>   cannot find -lopencv_imgcodecs collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit
>   status Makefile:619: recipe for target
>   '.build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin' failed make: ***
>   [.build_release/tools/convert_imageset.bin] Error 1

I search about it and tried

```
cd build
cmake ..
make all
make test
make runtest
make pycaffe
make distribute
```

It works fine for me and I add caffe to PYTHONPATH then I can use "import caffe" line. But when I tried one of pre-trained caffe models from this [site](http://caffe.berkeleyvision.org/gathered/examples/finetune_flickr_style.html) and write that to console :

```
caffe % ./examples/finetune_flickr_style/assemble_data.py -h
```

I get this error:

> No command 'caffe' found, did you mean:  Command 'caff' from package
>   'signing-party' (universe) caffe: command not found

Answer (score 0):

I myself solve the error

> No command 'caffe' found, did you mean: Command 'caff' from package 'signing-party' (universe) caffe: command not found

this way:
Instead of writing in terminal just `caffe <...>` I write `/my/path/to/caffe/build/tools/caffe <...>`. The same way I do, for example, `convert_imageset` to get lmdb: `/my/path/to/caffe/build/tools/convert_imageset <...>`. In other words, I always specify Caffe directory.

Comment: This is not a good solution. This just highlights the fact that your `PATH` is incomplete.